# getUserMedia in Firefox 20

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, getusermedia

I'm having serious trouble in getting getUserMedia to work in Firefox 20. What I would need is a simple webcam capture.

I've tried a couple of examples over the web, here's one for example:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Is it so that Chrome is actually the only browser supporting the getUserMedia properly today? I've also tried photobooth.js with no luck. Any good solutions around?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have not gone through Mozilla [documentation on getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC/navigator.getUserMedia)

Comment: I have, and unfortunately didn't get any help from those.. :/

Answer (score 0):

[Chrome 21+, Firefox 17+ and Opera 12+ actually support `getUserMedia`](http://caniuse.com/stream) (been using it as well). But Chrome and Firefox still prefix them with `webkit` and `moz`, respectively, so [you need a simple polyfill](https://github.com/addyosmani/getUserMedia.js) to patch up the differences.

I read somewhere before that the initial versions of these browsers that supported these features had them disabled by default. You need to enable them first. As far as I have used these browsers, the latest versions have them enabled (FF20 and GC26)

In order to use `getUserMedia`, it has to be hosted on a web server. An error will be thrown if you try to run the page locally. If you have NodeJS installed, you can run [this little NodeJS script](https://gist.github.com/rpflorence/701407) to run a portable static file server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you check if the html5rocks -page webcam capture part works with your Firefox 20 as for me it doesn't and I do have the media.navigator enabled in the config. I've ran all the tests on a server.

Comment: @underpaid_pedro apparently, they are developing for Chrome. The page tells me Firefox 20 doesn't. You might want to check their code.

Answer (score 0):

in webkit you hve to prefix webkit and in moz you need prefix moz . you can use [adapter.js](https://apprtc.appspot.com/js/adapter.js) as polyfil so you can call the same function to work in all web rtc enabled browser . And web rtc still have problem in chrome to moz or moz to chrome Peer connection

you are needed to enable flags in chrome 24 or less . but with chrome 25+ it is flagless